# Showing the remainder of a Taylor series is bounded by some sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have the function $$f(z)=\frac{z^{2}+1}{z^{10}-2}$$
and I wish to show $$|R_{n}(z)|<\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$
for its Taylor series around $0$, for all $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$.

I thought I should use $$R_{n}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(z-z_{0})^{n+1}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z_{0})^{n+1}(w-z)}\,\mathrm dw$$
considering $\gamma$, a circle of radius $r_1$ around $z_0=0$. Also, if we denote $r_0=\frac12$, it is clear that $$|w-z|=|(w-z_{0})-(z-z_{0})|\geq r_{1}-r$$ from the inverse triangle inequality. We can also notice that
$$|w-z_0| = |w| = r_1$$
and get after the integral evaluation:
$$|R_{n}(z)|\leq\frac{\max\limits_{w\in\gamma}|f(w)|}{1-r/r_1}\left(\frac{r}{r_{1}}\right)^{n+1}$$

But I can't seem to see a way to proceed from here. It obviously has something to do with finding the maximum of the function on the circle, but that doesn't seem to lead me to the answer. I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\i{\mathrm{i}}\def\N{\mathbb{N}}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}$Note that for any $|z| < 1$,$$
f(z) = -\frac{1}{2} (z^2 + 1) · \frac{1}{1 - \dfrac{z^{10}}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} (z^2 + 1) \sum_{k = 0}^∞ \paren{ \frac{z^{10}}{2} }^k = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^∞ \paren{ \frac{z^{10k}}{2^k} + \frac{z^{10k + 2}}{2^k} }.
$$
Define$$
a_j = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{2^{k + 1}}; & j = 10k\ \text{or}\ 10k + 2\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},
$$
then $f(z) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^∞ a_j z^j$, which implies that\begin{align*}
T_n(z) &= \sum_{j = 0}^n a_j z^j\\
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} (a_{10k} z^{10k} + a_{10k + 2} z^{10k + 2}) + a_{10m} z^{10m}; & 10m \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 1\\
\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^m (a_{10k} z^{10k} + a_{10k + 2} z^{10k + 2}); & 10m + 2 \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 9
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1} \paren{ \frac{z^{10k}}{2^{10k}} + \frac{z^{10k + 2}}{2^{10k + 2}} } + \frac{z^{10m}}{2^{10m}}; & 10m \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 1\\
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 0}^m \paren{ \frac{z^{10k}}{2^{10k}} + \frac{z^{10k + 2}}{2^{10k + 2}} }; & 10m + 2 \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 9
\end{cases},
\end{align*}
and thus$$
R_n(z) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2} \paren{ \frac{z^{10m + 2}}{2^m} + \sum_{k = m + 1}^∞ \paren{ \frac{z^{10k}}{2^k} + \frac{z^{10k + 2}}{2^k} } }; & 10m \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 1\\
\displaystyle  -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = m + 1}^∞ \paren{ \frac{z^{10k}}{2^k} + \frac{z^{10k + 2}}{2^k} }; & 10m + 2 \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 9
\end{cases}.
$$
Therefore, if $10m \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 1$, then\begin{align*}
|R_n(z)| &\leqslant \frac{1}{2} \paren{ \frac{|z|^{10m + 2}}{2^m} + \sum_{k = m + 1}^∞ \paren{ \frac{|z|^{10k}}{2^k} + \frac{|z|^{10k + 2}}{2^k} } }\\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{2} \paren{ \frac{1}{2^{11m + 2}} + \sum_{k = m + 1}^∞ \paren{ \frac{1}{2^{11k}} + \frac{1}{2^{11k + 2}} } }\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{10m + 1}} \paren{ \frac{1}{2^{m + 2}} + \frac{2^{11}}{2^{11} - 1} · \frac{5}{2^{m + 13}} } < \frac{1}{2^{10m + 1}} · \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align*}
If $10m + 2 \leqslant n \leqslant 10m + 9$, then\begin{align*}
|R_n(z)| &\leqslant \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = m + 1}^∞ \paren{ \frac{|z|^{10k}}{2^k} + \frac{|z|^{10k + 2}}{2^k} } \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = m + 1}^∞ \paren{ \frac{1}{2^{11k}} + \frac{1}{2^{11k + 2}} }\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{10m + 9}} · \paren{ \frac{2^{11}}{2^{11} - 1} · \frac{5}{2^{m + 5}} } < \frac{1}{2^{10m + 9}} · \frac{1}{6} < \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! Could you please just explain more in detail why is that the expression for $R_n$ and why you defined it in two different cases?

Comment: @Darkenin $R_n$'s are derived out of a basic property of power series/analytic functions: If $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^∞a_nz^n$ for $|z|<R$, then $f^{(n)}(0)=n!\,a_n$ for all $n$. Since many coefficients in the power series of $\dfrac{z^2+1}{z^{10}-2}$ are $0$, it's clearer to write the explicit expression of $R_n$ by cases.

Comment: I tried writing it explicitly but I still fail to see how you received the expression after "which implies that". Sorry if that's trivial, I just don't see it.

Comment: @Darkenin I've added some details.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lvert z\rvert < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\lvert w - z_0\rvert = 1$, then

1. $\lvert(z - z_0)^{n + 1}\rvert < \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}$,
2. $\lvert(w - z_0)^{n + 1}\rvert = 1$,
3. $\lvert w - z\rvert > \frac{1}{2}$,
4. $\lvert w^2 + 1\rvert \leq 2$, and
5. $\lvert w^{10} - 2\rvert \geq 1$.

Therefore,
$$\lvert R_n(z)\rvert < \frac{1} {2 \pi} \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} 2 \pi \frac{2 / 1} {1 \cdot 1 / 2}.$$

If you really need the stronger bound of $\frac{1}{2^n}$, you'll need a different way to estimate the remainder, since using a different radius will still not get you the bound you want. The only other approach I can think of would be either directly calculating the integral or directly calculating the remainder.

Comment: Thank you, but I do need the stronger bound. Any idea on how to proceed? also, why would $|w-z_0|=1$?

Comment: That would be the curve $\gamma$. Do you know the Reside Theorem?

Comment: Never mind, all the Residue Theorem tells us is that the remainder is the difference between the function and its Taylor polynomial.